# C - Creating Sub Function To realloc Array Size

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, realloc

I'm having an issue with pointers. I've read through 30+ posts on this subject and none match my setup. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
void doSomething(myStruct **myList)
{
    resizeMyList(myList,5);

    myList[0] = '42';
    myList[1] = '43'; // ERRORS OUT OF MEMORY
}

void resizeMyList(myStruct **theArray,int size)
{
    myStruct *new_ptr = realloc(*theArray,(size * sizeof myStruct));

    if(new_ptr)
         *theArray = new_ptr;
    else
         printf("died");
}
```

After my resize function executes myList fails to get the new pointer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you add more details? do you get new_ptr=NULL? and what's with the comment ERRORS OUT OF MEMORY?

Comment: `sizeof myStruct` is not your real code, that won't compile. It should be `sizeof *new_ptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do

```
myList[0] = ...
```

but `myList` is a double pointer so it should be

```
(*myList)[0] = ...
```

Also, you try to assign multi-character literals to a structure.

Comment: Wow, parens?? I was actually doing the *myList, and forgot to put it in my sample code. After adding it, it worked. Amazing how the littlest things make all the difference. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkLöwe It's due to the [operator precedence rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), array subscripting has higher precedence than pointer dereference.